# Error when adding rows to OutputBuffer in parallel

Tags: c#, multithreading, ssis, parallel-processing

I am facing a problem an it really drives me insane: I have to handle a bunch of XML files (something like 70k a day) and wrote a Sourcecomponent which does a pretty good job in transforming (XSL) and loading the files (Yes, I tried the XML Source; No, it does not fullfill my needs). However, I designed the source component in order to first load a certain amount of data into  memory tables and after this amount is reached send the data from the tables to the OutputBuffer and in order to speed things up a little, I do this by `Parallel.For`. The first part - the loading and transforming - works pretty fine and I can load an example set of 200 files in a few seconds. But when it comes to `OutputBuffer.AddRow`, the program crashes, reporting errors of various types (wrong data type, etc.). If I send the content of the data tables separately, everything seems to work. Any idea, why `OutputBuffer.AddRow` crashes when it is called from within `Parallel.For`???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is typeof `OutputBuffer`? very likely, a type not thread safe, requiring some syncronization when calling a method on it.
Can you try locking the access to it? instead of

```
OutputBuffer.AddRow(...)
```

something like

```
lock(OutputBuffer)
{
    OutputBuffer.AddRow(...);
}
```

Comment: Damn it - this did the trick!!! Thank you so much! The OutputBuffer is the "standard" type when creating a ScriptComponent as Source in a Dataflow. However, seemingly it is - indeed - not threadsafe.